# Не работает закрытие выпадающего контента при нажатии на него же

Tags: javascript, html

есть выпадающий контент
[image: <div class="accordion_tab">Name]
Он открывается исправно. При переключении на другой tab, предыдущий закрывается и открывается новый.

Проблема заключается в том, что когда tab открыт, закрыть его по нажатию на тот же tab не получается.
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]
Помогите, пожалуйста.

```js
$(".accordion_tab").click(function () {
  $(".accordion_tab").each(function () {
    $(this).removeClass("active");
  });
  $(this).addClass("active");
  $(this).next().addClass("active");
});
```

```html
<div class="accordion_wrapper">
    <div class="accordion_item">
      <div class="accordion_tab">Name
        <div class="arrow">
          <img src="**" alt="arrow">
        </div>
      </div>
      <div class="accordion_content"> 
        <div class="slider">
          <input type="radio" name="slider" title="slide1" checked="checked" class="slider__nav" />
          <input type="radio" name="slider" title="slide2" class="slider__nav" />
          <input type="radio" name="slider" title="slide3" class="slider__nav" />
          <input type="radio" name="slider" title="slide4" class="slider__nav" />
          <input type="radio" name="slider" title="slide5" class="slider__nav" />
          
          <div class="slider__inner">
            <div class="slider__contents"><img src="**">
              <h2 class="slider__caption">**</h2>
              <p class="slider__txt">**</p>
            </div>
            ....
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Добавляйте, пожалуйста, все необходимые данные, в том числе css таким образом, чтобы проблему можно было воспроизвести, а не дописывать недостающие части. Это в разы увеличит и скорость ответа и его качество.

Comment: Здравствуйте, понял. В следующий раз сделаю все правильно. Но мне уже помогли, так что редактировать смысла не вижу. Спасибо

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
$(".accordion_tab").click(function () {
  if ($(this).hasClass("active")) {
    $(this).removeClass("active");
    $(this).next().removeClass("active");
    return;
  }
  $(".accordion_tab").each(function () {
    $(this).removeClass("active");
  });
  $(this).addClass("active");
  $(this).next().addClass("active");
});
```

Comment: Спасибо, все работает, через 5 минут отмечу правильным ответом

Comment: @SergeyMarano Пожалуйста. Успехов.